# UITableView adjusts top Y position when status bar disappears

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a view controller with a full screen `UITableView`. The tableView starts at superView y=0, so it's visible beneath my slightly transparent navigation bar.

The tableview has a top constraint to the superView and not to the statusBar margin, but when the status bar is called to disappear or reappear, the tableView shifts up and down 20pixels.

Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO` in your view controller, because status bar affect on your UITableView scroll insets